# Dado inteiro não salva na tabela como o Eloquent do Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho no meu banco de dados uma coluna chamada `permission` que dita as permissões dos usuários no meu sistema. Usuário 1 é administrador e usuário 0 não.

O problema é que quando vou salvar um novo usuário e seleciono através do select o tipo de permissão do usuário, ela salva todos os dados do usuário, menos o campo `permission` que é um `int(11)`. O que pode estar acontecendo?

**Migrate**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddPermissionToUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('permission');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropColumn('permission');
        });
    }

}
```

**View**

```
@extends('admin.painel.layout')

@section('conteudoPainel')

    <h2>Usuários: [Novo]</h2>

    {!! Form::open(['role' => 'form', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'admin.usuarios.store']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('Nome') !!}
        {!! Form::text('nome', Input::old('nome'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        <br />
        {!! Form::label('E-mail') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        <br />
        {!! Form::label('Senha') !!}
        {!! Form::password('senha', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        <br />
        {!! Form::label('Permissão') !!}<br />
        {!! Form::select('permissao', [0=>'Usuário padrão', 1=>'Administrador'], Input::old('permissao'), ['class'=>'input-sm', 'style'=> 'border: 1px solid #ccc;']) !!}
        <br />
        <br />

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></i> Cadastrar
        </button>

        <a href="/admin/usuarios" class="btn btn-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            Cancelar
        </a>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(NewUserFormRequest $request)
    {
        $data = [
            'name' => $request->get('nome'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->get('senha')),
            'permission' => $request->get('permissao')
        ];

        if($user = User::create($data)){
            return redirect()->to('admin/usuarios/'.$user->id."/edit")->with(['alertaOk' => 'Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!']);
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('admin/usuarios')->withErrors('Não foi possivel cadastrar o usuario. Entre em contato com o administrador para mais informações!');
        }

    }
```

Comment: o que retorna um `dd($request->get('permissao'))` ?

Comment: Quando seleciono administrador ele retorna 1, e quando seleciono usuário padrão ele retorna 0. Mas só salva no banco como 0.

Comment: Como está a propriedade `$fillable` no seu model `User` ?

Comment: `protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao utilizar o método `create` de um *model* Eloquent o Laravel atribui as propriedades via [*mass assignment*](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Por padrão o *model* `User` já vem com essa propriedade pré-preenchida:

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email'];

}
```

Como você adicionou um novo campo na sua tabela (o `permission`), você precisa adicionar também esse campo na propriedade para ele permitir que ele seja inserido a partir do `create()`:

```
protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', `permission`];
```

Como notado na documento, é preciso esse tipo de filtro para evitar um risco potencial de inserção de dados indesejados no banco, como o `id` ou até mesmo o `password` nesse caso.

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!

Comment: @Samuel, mesmo não sendo o escopo da pergunta, revise o código de seu form. Você está permitindo que o usuário altere a senha sem nenhuma confirmação prévia (a senha antiga). Também não existe a verificação de que a senha digitada está correta. Recomendo seriamente rever esses pontos, abraço!

Comment: Neste caso ele está apenas cadastrando um novo usuário, e não atualizando. Por este motivo não adicionei o campo de senha antiga. Mas valeu pela observação.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Mas acho legal aquelas confirmações de que a seja digitada está batendo, um segundo campo de "Confirmar Senha" :)

Comment: Segui o seu conselho e adicionei co campo de "confirmar senha" rsrsrsrsrs. Abraços!